# idapython: how to apply hexrays types to disassembly interface

Tags: ida, idapython, hexrays

I am using idapro 7.5 to get variable information from binaries.

Consider following simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i, N, array[10];

  N = atoi(argv[10]);

  array[N] = N;
  array[12] = N;
  array[0] = 8;

  for(i=0 ; i<N ; i++)
    array[i] = N;

  printf("%d %d\n", array[12], array[5]);
  return 0;
}
```

Using idapython, I can get function information like stack variables, their sizes, types, etc. using something like -

```
for ea in idautils.Functions():
    for mem in ida_struct.get_struc(idc.get_frame_id(ea)).members:
        name = ida_struct.get_member_name(mem.id)
        size = ida_struct.get_member_size(mem)
        offset = mem.get_soff()
```

Similarly, I can get global variable information like their name and addresses.

Now, this works fine (particularly in above binary) and I can get array with a size of 12 on correct offset (this makes sense, as I have compiled binary using `-g`).

But, when I strip the binary, I can't get array size correctly with the above code (this is expected). When I use hex rays -

[image]

Here, ida decompiler was able to recover correct array bounds using decompiler algorithms. And I can also synchronize this with disassembly interface using `Synchronize with` option in Gui (I assume synchronize function is used to apply predicted types or other information to disassembly interface - I maybe wrong here, please forgive my ignorance).

I would like to know if there is any way I can do that using idapython (I can see some endpoints like `sync_sources` in `ida_kernwin`), so that I can use the above code to get variable properties predicted using hex rays. I am familiar with ghidra and you can apply ghidra decompiler predictions to the listing analysis (just like synchronization in ida) using:

```
HighFunctionDBUtil.commitLocalsToDatabase(high_func, SourceType.ANALYSIS)
```

Thus variables get updated in the analysis.

> Edit: I can manually get function variables using hexrays decompiler
> interface like -
>
> ```
> def get_local_vars(ea, stack_size):
>     # can be used to get member size, type, etc.
>     for var in ida_hexrays.decompile(ea).get_lvars():
>         print(var.name)
>         print(-stack_size + var.get_stkoff())
>         print(var.width)
> ```
>
> Still, I was not able to find an automatic way to apply hexrays
> decompiler interface or sync hexrays decompiler interface with
> disassembly interface.

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific about what you want. Generally speaking, it's not always possible to take the type information from Hex-Rays' stack variables and apply it to the disassembly stack frame. There are two main reasons for this, off the top of my head: mapped variables eliminating Hex-Rays stack variables, and forced variables creating more than one variable at a single stack location.

Comment: Rolf, Thanks for your reply, in short I want to use type (mostly array bounds) information predicted by hexrays, in case of stripped binaries. I am aware of the reasons you mentioned. but, I am doing this to check what results i could get on certain benchmarks. Also, as there is an option for sync in gui, I am interested in checking it's capability.

Comment: Also, please note that I assumed "synchronization" means applying hexrays predicted information to disassembly interface, if this is not true then forgive my ignorance

Comment: “Synchronize with” only syncs the cursor location in both views.

Comment: ahh, thanks Igor, in that case, "synchronize with" is not what I want to do. I'd like to "apply" decompiler predictions to the disassembly interface. Is this automatically possible at all?

Comment: That's easy. You get the type (`tinfo_t`) from the variable, and apply it to the correct member of the stack frame.

Comment: thanks! I figured that out!